# std::futures in (non-)boost asio

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, future

I'm doing some small exercises in functional language paradigmas by implementing monadic return/bind/join for std::future. As a practical example to work with I decided to use the std::futures (optionally) returned by asio's async_xyz functions.

Since then I was searching my code for the reason why my reads block infinitely, until I tried the example code provided by boost-asio / standalone-asio you can see here:

https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/src/examples/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp

A recv_length.get() / .wait() after the async read call (at line 55) will also block infinitely. I also changed the service to use port 5004 just in case there is a socket permission problem.

I then digged through the rather short asio handler code for asio::use_future that you can see here:

https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/impl/use_future.hpp

A small debug output reveals, that the corresponding value is already read and the corresponding as well as correct size passed to the code at line 55.

I am therefore at a point where the value for the promise is set and the future called for the value. Since I found exactly 0 other incidents where anyone has this problem I assume I did *something* wrong (and from my limited experience with promises/futures the asio code seems perfectly fine).

Can anyone give me a hint where the problem might be?

I'm using g++ version 4.9.2 and compile with

```
g++ -o daytime_client daytime_client.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

(I already tried additionally appending -lpthread)

Greetings,
Richard

Comment: I've checked the example and it seems to be working. There is no blocking. Are you responding properly with your server ? What I did what # nc -luv 13 , I waited for a message (actually, I changed the code to send a \n) and then I responded.

Comment: Sorry for late response, was a bit hectic here around west german carnival. You are actually completely right. However with gnu netcat # nc -luv 13 does not work for me (reverse lookup failed) and (what I used) # nc -luv localhost 13 neither (silently does nothing). Correct listen command would have been # nc -luv -p 13 localhost. That makes my testing procedure the source of error - however I still wonder why the callback handler has been called with success error code. I will investigate this further. Thank you, Richard.